# Can I interpolate a timestamp?

Tags: drone.io

I want to rsync some files into a timestamped folder on a remote host. That
would require something like:

```
pipeline:
  deploy:
    image: drillster/drone-rsync
    hosts: ["foo.com"]
    source: "./build/"
    target: "/home/app/deploy/${TIMESTAMP}/"
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drone offers three distinct timestamp variables as part of the [environment
interpolation](http://readme.drone.io/0.5/usage/environment-reference/) done
before the yaml file is loaded:

```
DRONE_BUILD_CREATED
DRONE_BUILD_STARTED
DRONE_BUILD_FINISHED
```

Of these, the last is probably close enough in time to what would be generated
by the theoretical example in the question, just off by a few seconds at worst.
It's certainly good enough to timestamp deployments.